# Set datasource of combobox in devexpress in gridview c#

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I am trying to create a gridview with list as you can see

[image]

I add the item of the list using this code :

```
 private void frmDocument_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            gridControlDocument.DataSource = new BindingList<Document>(_documentRepository.Get().ToList()) { AllowNew = true };
            DisciplineList.Items.Add("ali");

        }
```

but i need to get data from the database ,but the `DisciplineList` doesn't have the datasource property .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ComboBoxEdit control is not meant to be bound to a data source. You would need to either loop through your DisciplineList collection and add each item manually, or use the [LookUpEdit control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic), which does offer a data source property.

In your case, you can add a RepsositoryItemLookUpEdit to the GridControl (See: [Assigning Editors for In-Place Editing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3085)) and set its DataSource property to your collection. Additionally, set the ValueMember and DisplayMember properties to a property within the Discipline class.

Comment: So what about value id ?

Comment: If you're using it as a lookup, you'd typically have a data source that has an ID value (which might correspond to an ID field in your database).

Comment: could you please take a look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606931/groupbox-in-devexpress-gridview-in-c-sharp