# ListBox in devexpress gridview in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, listbox, devexpress

I have a gridview as you can see here:

[image]

As you can see i read the data in `materialrequestcontractorId` i have a listbox that this listbox reads its value from the database as you can see here:

```
List<MaterialRequestContractor> lstMRC = _materialRequestContractorRepository.Get().ToList();
            foreach (MaterialRequestContractor VARIABLE in lstMRC)
            {
                LstMaterialRequestContractorId.Items.Add(VARIABLE.Id);
            }
```

But the problem is i need to show my user the name of my `MaterialRequestContractor` not its `id` ,the id should be the value of my name and be saved in database .but in devexpress i can't assign this value and text to list box?

```
I have a record in my MaterialRequestContractor database with id=1
```

Comment: What kind of editor did you assign to the "materialrequestcontractorId" GridColumn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress provides several lookup editors for WinForms (LookUpEdit, GridLookUpEdit, SearchLookUpEdit) which support such scenario out-of-the-box. The idea is that LookUp editor has its own data source. When it is shown in the grid, it finds a value with from the grid cell in its data source (the key column determined by the LookUpEdit.Properties.ValueMember property) and shows the value from a field that selected as DisplayMember. 
So if you put a table that has MaterialRequestContractor and MaterialRequestContractorId fields, and properly select DisplayMember and ValueMember, the DevExpress grid should work just like you described.

Comment: I changed it to listboxitem but i have a problem here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657217/casting-devexpress-gridview-column-to-checkedlistboxitem-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655058/get-the-value-of-checkedlistboxitem-devexpress-in-gridview-c-sharp#