# Get the value of CheckedListBoxItem devexpress in gridview c#

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I put a `CheckedListBoxItem` in `grivviewDevexpress` as you can see here :

[image]

I initialize the datasource in `page_load` as you can see  :

```
 List<User> confirms = _userRepository.Get().ToList();
            ConfirmList.DataSource = confirms;
            ConfirmList.DisplayMember = "FullName";
            ConfirmList.ValueMember = "Id";
```

In save button I need to get the selected values(more than one selections) by user but it returns null why ?

```
 private void btnSave_ItemClick_1(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
 {
     gridView.CloseEditor();
     Convert.ToDateTime(gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "ReturnDateTime"));
     CheckedListBoxItem confirms =(CheckedListBoxItem)(gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "Confirm"));
 }
```

Comment: what do you store in the "Confirm" column?? as i can see from the data source of the list. it should had similar datatype as you have for the Id property of User.

Comment: @NiranjanKala what does it mean ?I explained in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can suspect about your code that you are casting `gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "Confirm")` returned value to invalid type. Change the below your below line of code by using the `as` operator.

```
CheckedListBoxItem confirms =(CheckedListBoxItem)(gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "Confirm"));
```

to

```
CheckedListBoxItem confirms = gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "Confirm") as CheckedListBoxItem;
if(confirms != null){}
```

After doing that you will know get what is the result to debug.

As i can see that editor is attached with the column `Confirm` then you will get the result from `gridView.GetRowCellValue()` is `Id` property value of the `User` class not the `CheckedListBoxItem`.

When you call the `gridView.CloseEditor();` then editor will not exist to get the CheckedListBoxItem. You can access the editor on the [ColumnView.ShownEditor Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShownEditortopic). See the below code snippet:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.PhonesSource.DataSource = DataContext.GetPhones();
    this.CountriesSource.DataSource = DataContext.GetCountries();
    this.CitiesSource.DataSource = DataContext.GetAllCities();
}

private void GridView_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ColumnView view = (ColumnView)sender;
    if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "CityCode") {
        LookUpEdit editor = (LookUpEdit)view.ActiveEditor;
        string countryCode = Convert.ToString(view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("CountryCode"));
        editor.Properties.DataSource = DataContext.GetCitiesByCountryCode(countryCode);
    }
}

// In certain scenarios you may want to clear the secondary editor's value
// You can use the RepositoryItem.EditValueChanged event for this purpose
private void CountryEditor_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.GridView.PostEditor();
    this.GridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CityCode", null);
}


    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.PhonesSource.DataSource = DataContext.GetPhones();
        this.CountriesSource.DataSource = DataContext.GetCountries();
        this.CitiesSource.DataSource = DataContext.GetAllCities();
    }

    private void GridView_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ColumnView view = (ColumnView)sender;
        if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "CityCode") {
            LookUpEdit editor = (LookUpEdit)view.ActiveEditor;
            string countryCode = Convert.ToString(view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("CountryCode"));
            editor.Properties.DataSource = DataContext.GetCitiesByCountryCode(countryCode);
        }
    }
```

Hope this help..

Comment: thank you for your code ,but it doesn't work again it returns null

Comment: you solution is similar to my suggestion that you will only get the key from the grid cell after selection. You can fetch actual record from the data source using these key.. If your list allow multi select then your question is not relevant to your question text. nobody can judge that you want to fetch  multiple values from the list.. It's great that you solved the issue

Answer (score -1):

I think the casting type is the problem.

Comment: which casting i should use?