# Casting Devexpress gridview column to CheckedListBoxItem c#

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, listboxitem

I have a column int my gridview with `CheckedListBoxItem` type.I need the value of this in my submit button as you can see here :

```
private void btnSave_ItemClick_1(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
 {
     gridView.CloseEditor();
     Convert.ToDateTime(gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "ReturnDateTime"));
     CheckedListBoxItem confirms =(CheckedListBoxItem)(gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "Confirm"));
 }
```

,

My confirms  is not ,i think because of `GetRowCellValue` because it returns string .how can i use correct casting ?

Comment: that string value must be some id in data source.. so you can find that Row or Object from the data data source with the help of value returned by GetRowCellValue method.

Comment: What datatype are you expecting?  Are you wanting the index of the checked list box?